# rails 3 fields_for nested forms multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, fields-for, multiple-records

Maybe someone here will help me.

I've got the following model `vehicle.rb`:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :parameters_attributes
  has_many :parameters, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parameters, reject_if: lambda {
  |attrs| attrs.all? {
    |tag, value|
      value.is_a?(Integer)
      tag.blank?
    }
  }
end
```

`vehicles_controller.rb`

```
def new
  @vehicle = Vehicle.new
end
```

and in my view `new.html.haml`:

```
= form_for [:admin, setup(@vehicle)], html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  %fieldset{ data: { hook: "new_vehicle" } }
    %legend{ align: "center" }
      = t(:new_vehicle)
  = render partial: 'shared_vehicle_fields', locals: { f: f }
  = f.field_container :size do
  = f.label :size
  %span.required *
  %br/
  = f.select :size, [t(:please_select) , "small", "medium", "large"], class: 'require'
  .parameter_fields
  %div.small_vehicle_parameters
    = f.fields_for :parameters do |pf|
      = render 'parameter_fields', f: pf, text: 'A1'
    = f.fields_for :parameters do |pf|
      = render 'parameter_fields', f: pf, text: 'A2'
  %div.medium_vehicle_parameters
  %div.large_vehicle_parameters
  %br/
  = f.submit t(:submit)
```

the `setup(@vehicle)` is the following helper:

```
def setup(vehicle)
  returning(vehicle) do |car|
    car.parameters.build if car.parameters.blank?
  end
end
```

the partial `parameter_fields` is nothing special, but I'll show it just in case:

```
= f.label :tag, text
= f.text_field :value, size: 4
= f.hidden_field :tag, { value: text }
%br/
```

Now, the problem is this:

When I type in the correct values in any of the fields of the form everything is fine. It creates the models and records as I want them. But, if any of the validation doesn't pass the form is rendered again with error message. However, the parameter text_fields are multiplied. I get 2 `fields_for` with tag `A1` and 2 fields with `tag` `A2`. If I had 3 `fields_for`, then there would be 3 of each and so on.

I know how many records I need to create in table (depends on vehicle size), if that helps.

Help, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might run into a similar problem and is stunned as I was....

What happen was, after the failed validation the `@vehicle.parameters` had a list of records he wanted to create, which, in turn, made render that amount of `text_fields` for each `fields_for` there was on the page. That's how this is made, Ruby on Rails is smart like that. This comes handy when editing the form. He automatically renders the 'right' amount of fields. At least that's how I understood the problem.

Anyways, I've added the following line in the `create` action if the `save` was unsuccessful.

```
@vehicle.parameters = []
```